# Broken link detection

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, hyperlinks

Here is an example. On this page: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits there is a link `suggested edits tab in the review section` that redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits at the bottom of page.

Is there any strategy or mechanism to detect or notify SE of broken links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug.

You still don't have the required 5,000 reputation points to see that page.

It's there for convenience for those who do have enough reputation, so I don't think it's good idea to remove it.

It's possible to add explicit text saying something like *5000 reputation required in order to see that page* but I think it's pretty clear from the whole page context.